# How to Prove limit does not Exists

Tags: limits

$$f(x)  = \begin{cases} 2x^2 + 7x +1 & x \ge 1 \\
              3x + 4     & x<1    \end{cases}$$

I want to show that the limit does not exists when x tends to 1.
I can show that the right side limit and the left side limit are not equal to each other.but is there any method in mathematics to prove that the limit does not exists using delta epsilon???

Can anybody please help me..

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $7 \neq 10$ qed

Comment: First, compute the left and right hand limits at $x=1$.

Comment: I tried to solve it assuming that x tends to some constant .and to step further.but it was a faliure.

Comment: Hint: Show that for every positive $\delta$, $$\left|f(1-\delta)-f(1)\right|\geqslant3,$$ then, "using delta epsilon", explain why this fact forbids that $f$ is continuous at $1$.

Comment: thanks alot..this would help me... @Did

Comment: Then do it. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens as $x$ approaches 1 from the positive side (the right)?
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1^+} f(x) = ???$$

What happens as $x$ approaches 1 from the negative side (the left)?
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = ???$$

You should use the formula for $x>1$ when approaching from the right. Likewise, you should use the formula for $x<1$ when approaching from the left.

Also, keep in mind that a limit does not exist if the left and right limits don't match.

**Edit:** For a formal epsilon-delta argument...

We know the left limit is 7 and the right limit is 10. So picking $\epsilon=1$ (7 and 10 are farther apart than this) will give us our desired contradiction.

Suppose there is some limit $L$. Let $\epsilon=1$, suppose $\delta>0$. Then given $x=1-\delta/2$ should give us $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon=1$. This means $|3x+4-L| = |3(1-\delta/2)+4-L|<1$ ($x<1$ so we use the formula $3x+4$) so $|7-1.5\delta-L|<1$ and so $L<(7-1.5\delta)+1<8$.

Likewise, $x=1+\delta/2$ should give us $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon=1$. Thus $|2x^2+7x+1-L| = |2(1+\delta/2)^2+7(1+\delta/2)+1-L| = |10+5.5\delta+0.5\delta^2-L|<1$ ($x>1$ tell us to use the other formula). Therefore, $(10+5.5\delta+0.5\delta^2)-1 < L$ but this means $9<L$ so $L<8$ and $L>9$ (thus no $L$ exists).

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response.I can show that the right side limit and the left side limit are not equal.but is there some method to prove this using delta epsilon?????

Comment: This question and answers may help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212672/delta-varepsilon-proof-of-limit/1212730#1212730